# WPF ListView - selecting item that was just added to items source

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a ListView in my WPF application, data bound to an ObservableCollection, like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="listChecks" ItemsSource="{Binding Checks}" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Margin="3 0 0 0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and here's the property in the code-behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<CheckItem> Checks {get; set;}
```

Now, when the user clicks a button, I want to add a new item to the collection and make it the selected item in the ListView, like this:

```
private void BtnAddCheck_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var newCheck = new CheckItem()
    {
        Name = "New check"
    };            
    Checks.Add(newCheck);

    listChecks.SelectedIndex = Checks.Count - 1;
}
```

However, this does not work: the item does not get selected in the list. My guess is that the new item will only be detected when the event handler returns and data bindings are updated.

In facto, I managed to make it work by forcing a layout update between adding the item to the collection and changing the selected index, like this:

```
private void BtnAddCheck_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var newCheck = new CheckItem()
    {
        Name = "New check"
    };            
    Checks.Add(newCheck);

    this.UpdateLayout(); //This fixes the problem

    listChecks.SelectedIndex = Checks.Count - 1;
}
```

However, I'm not sure if this approach is correct, it kinda feels like a hack... is there a better way to do this, or is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: How about `listChecks.SelectedItem = newCheck;`? Note also that since you are apparently not setting the ListView's View property, you may as well use the simpler ListBox (i.e. the base class of ListView).

Comment: If synchronously setting SelectedItem doesn't work, do it asynchronously. Declare the Click handler async, and call `await task.Delay(1); listChecks.SelectedItem = newCheck;`.

Comment: @Clemens: I've tried using SelectedItem, but same result. As for using the async method with a delay: I think it would probably work, but to me it looks like more of a hack than simply calling UpdateLayout()

Comment: Another way would be to add an IsSelected property to the CheckItem class and bind the ListBoxItem's IsSelected property to that property in an ItemContainerStyle.

Comment: @Master_T I believe the code posted is working without using this.updatelayout(). Is any other piece of code you missed out to post?

Comment: @neeleshbodgal: not really, however I'm not using "vanilla" WPF, I'm using the MaterialDesignInXaml toolkit to give it a "material design" look and feel... maybe their custom style for the LIstView is interfering with normal execution... I'll ask on their github I guess

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, the most straightforward solution seems to be the one I was doing in the first place, i.e.: manually forcing a layout refresh:

```
private void BtnAddCheck_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var newCheck = new CheckItem()
    {
        Name = "New check"
    };            
    Checks.Add(newCheck);

    this.UpdateLayout(); //This fixes the problem

    listChecks.SelectedIndex = Checks.Count - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The item does get *selected* in your example but the visual container doesn't *focused*.

You could focus it by adding an `ItemContainerStyle` and handle the `Loaded` event for the `ListViewItem` container:

```
private void ListViewItem_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = (ListViewItem)sender;
    if (lvi.IsSelected)
        lvi.Focus();
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListView x:Name="listChecks" ItemsSource="{Binding Checks}" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="ListViewItem_Loaded" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Margin="3 0 0 0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```